# Executing python subprocess via git hook

Tags: python, git, subprocess, pipe

I'm running Gitolite over the Git repository and I have post-receive hook there written in Python. I need to execute "git" command at git repository directory. There are few lines of code:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'log', '-n1'], cwd='/home/git/repos/testing.git' stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate()
```

After I make new commit and push to repository, scripts executes and says

```
fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

If I run

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['pwd'], cwd='/home/git/repos/testing.git' stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

it says, as expected, correct path to git repository (/home/git/repos/testing.git)

If I run this script manually from bash, it works correct and show correct output of "git log". What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to set the git repository using a command-line switch:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', '--git-dir', '/home/git/repos/testing.git', 'log', '-n1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

`--git-dir` needs to point to an actual git directory (`.git` in a working tree). Note that for some commands you *also* need to set a `--work-tree` option too.

Another way to set the directory is using the `GIT_DIR` environment variable:

```
import os
env = os.environ.copy()
env['GIT_DIR'] = '/home/git/repos/testing.git'
proc = subprocess.Popen((['git', 'log', '-n1', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=env)
```

Apparently hooks already set `GIT_DIR` but obviously this is incorrect for your case (it could be relative); the above code sets it to a full, explicit path.

See the [`git` manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.10.1/git.html).

Edit: Apparently it only works for the OP when specifying both a cwd and overriding the `GIT_DIR` var:

```
import os
repo = '/home/git/repos/testing.git'
env = os.environ.copy()
env['GIT_DIR'] = repo
proc = subprocess.Popen((['git', 'log', '-n1', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=env, cwd=repo)
```

Comment: Hooks are run with the environment variable `$GIT_DIR` set already, so if you want to point git at a different directory, you have to override that.  Note that in general the hook is run with `GIT_DIR=.` as well (i.e., it's *relative*, which was a surprise to me).  Best to either clear it out entirely or set it to what you want though.

Comment: @torek: interesting, this may be what is wrong for the OP. Updated the answer, as `env.update(os.environ)` would have wiped the custom `GIT_DIR` var we are trying to set.

Comment: Oh, hah, I didn't read your second part of your answer closely enough to realize that you were using `.update` that way.  Anyway, yes, I suspect that's the OP's real issue.  (Experimentation tells me that `--git-dir` overrides `$GIT_DIR` so your first answer should work.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't even expect any env vars here. Now, it only works with redefined 'GIT_DIR' variable AND specified 'cwd' option in Popen method. Please add it to your answer.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I've been trying some solutions but yours (in the edit section ) is the best and simplest that I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma missing after the cwd argument:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'log', '-n1'], cwd='/home/git/repos/testing.git', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: That can hardly be it; that would give a SyntaxError, not the error the user saw. Prolly a transciption error when posting on SO.